# Struggling to build Qt due to missing OpenGL libraries

Tags: compiling, qt, libraries, opengl

I'm trying to build an executable Qt-based program for Linux, and link Qt statically in the binary. According to the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html#building-qt-statically), to do this I'm going to need to build Qt from source, starting with the commands:

```
cd /path/to/Qt
./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt
```

when I try this, I get a long bunch of output ending with:

```
ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.

Check config.log for details.
```

This isn't the first time I had problems with OpenGL and Qt... when I built my program with dynamic linking (using binary Qt libs) I got a similar problem, which I solved by symlinking to `libGL.so` from `/usr/lib`.

The output from `configure` said to go and find the "mkspec" for my platform, so I looked at `Qt/5.13.1/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++-64` (I explicitly told it to use that platform with the `-platform` command). I rooted around and tried setting those envvars to various combinations of paths that seemed plausible, to no avail.

It also mentioned a `config.log` file. When I look in this file, I can see open GL mentioned only in this block:

```
loaded result for library config.qtbase_gui.libraries.opengl
Trying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library opengl ...
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --exists --silence-errors gl
pkg-config did not find package.
  => source produced no result.
Trying source 1 (type makeSpec) of library opengl ...
Include path /usr/include/libdrm is invalid.
header entry 'config.qtbase_gui.libraries.opengl.headers.0' passed condition.
GL/gl.h not found in [/usr/include/libdrm] and global paths.
  => source produced no result.
test config.qtbase_gui.libraries.opengl FAILED
loaded result for library config.qtbase_gui.libraries.opengl_es2
Trying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library opengl_es2 ...
+ /usr/bin/pkg-config --exists --silence-errors glesv2
pkg-config did not find package.
  => source produced no result.
Trying source 1 (type makeSpec) of library opengl_es2 ...
None of [libGLESv2.so libGLESv2.a] found in [] and global paths.
  => source produced no result.
test config.qtbase_gui.libraries.opengl_es2 FAILED
```

Indeed `pkg-config --print-errors --exists gl` can't find anything. No idea where it's getting that `/usr/include/libdrm` path...

Comment: possibly `apt-get install libdrm-dev libgles2-mesa-dev` ?

Comment: @WayneVosberg doesn't seem to have done it. Same behavior, including `pkg-config` not finding anything.

Comment: For the record, in the end I gave up using Qt for this very reason and switched to GTK.

Comment: Here too... the very same annoying issue.

Comment: I can't abandon QT (Unless I code my own GUI library from scratch). Searching for viable solution now... It's pretty hard.

Comment: @AtomX Maybe try `apt install libgl-dev`?

Comment: That didn't work...

Comment: @Wayne Vosbergs comment was the solution for me:
```sudo apt-get install libdrm-dev libgles2-mesa-dev``` However, I did have to use a clean build directory (deleted everything in the build directory I had been using, then moved the files I needed to use to configure Qt back into the directory and performed the configure command: ```./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests```)

Comment: `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libx11-xcb-dev` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

Following the suggestion of @Michael_Hirsch I was able to generate a build file by installing the packages listed above by others, & then completely removing & re-cloning the repo off github.

(Qt5 is the project I was trying to compile)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1302563)